# Invalid get index 'get' (on base: 'RigidBody2D (bird.gd)') Error

Tags: godot

I have started my Godot learning from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLv3l-oZCXaql20IlPe7gfBEzomnPSLekY).

Right now I am only at the beginning of the tutorial, but I already struggling. I need somehow focus my camera on the "bird". But the command that is used from the tutorial gives me an error. I know this tutorial is outdated, but can i somehow focus my camera on the object in Godot(is there a specific command or function maybe)? This does not sound too complicated to implement.
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsldr.png), [node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgsZt.png)

```
extends Camera2D

var bird 

func _ready():
    bird = get_tree().get_root().get_child(0).get_node("bird")
    pass

func _physics_process(delta):
    set_position(Vector2(bird.get.position().x, get_position().y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice for trying Godot!

In `_physics_process` you're attempting to reference a member of `bird` called `get` which does not exist.

Simply replace the `.` with `_` to reference the `get_position()` method.

Final line should look like this:
`set_position(Vector2(bird.get_position().x, get_position().y))`